# What is Bottom-Hat transformation?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am reading the Digital Image Processing book by Gonzalez and i can't seem to understand Bottom-hat transformation. Can anyone explain it to me in easy terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation in Wikipedia for [Top-hat transform - Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-hat_transform#Properties) seems pretty simple, for the bottom-hat, another name for the black top-hat.

> The black top-hat returns an image, containing the "objects" or
> "elements" that:
>
> - are "smaller" than the structuring element,
> - are darker than their surroundings.